# How to Check inner class properties

Tags: c#, reflection

this is some class

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string Name    { get; set; }
    public string Color   { get; set; }
    public ClassB ClassB_ { get; set; }


    public class ClassB
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float  Age  { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, i want to print to console all the public properties of ClassA so i using this

( obj is some parameter that the method gets and print out all his properties )

```
 var allProp = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

But when my application sees the ClassB object of ClassA - i want to print out also all the ClassB properties - and i don't know how can i know in run time that ClassB is class and not primitive object and how in run time i can print out all ClassB properties ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("ClassA+ClassB");
var allProp = type.GetProperties();
```

If you need dynamic name of type try to use next code:

```
string fullname = typeof(ClassA.ClassB).FullName;
```

Comment: this is working - but in this case i don't know if the Type is string\int or some class that i define ... if the class is string/int or any of the primitive type - i don't want to print his properties

Comment: Check answers from this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424846/how-to-get-all-primitive-type-of-an-object it should help